# S-operator lorentz invariance

Tags: quantum-field-theory, s-matrix-theory, poincare-symmetry, lorentz-symmetry

How to show that $\hat {S}$-operator must be lorentz-invariant operator?

$$
|\Psi (t)\rangle = \hat {S} | \Psi (0) \rangle , \quad \hat {S} = \hat {T}e^{-i\int \hat {H}_{I}d^{4}x}.
$$
I have read that this result follows from the unitarity of the Poincare group operator $U_{0}(\Lambda , a)$ and the covariance of S-matrix $S_{out, in} = \langle out| \hat {S}|in \rangle$, but I don't understand how do we conclude that from this follows that $U_{0}(\Lambda , a)\hat {S}U^{-1}_{0}(\Lambda , a) = \hat {S}$.

I'm not interesting in the derivation of lorentz-invariance of S-operator from causality principle at this moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, without assuming it from first principles as in Bogoliubov formulation, the invariance property of $S$ operator you mention holds when the interaction Lagrangian does not include derivatives of fields like in QED. That is a consequence of Dyson's expansion in interaction picture. 
When,as said above,  the interaction Lagrangian does not include derivatives of fields, one has: 
$${\cal H}_I = -{\cal L}_I$$
so that
$$S = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{i^n}{n!} \int\cdots \int T \hat{\cal L}_I(x_1)\cdots
\hat{\cal L}_I(x_n) \:d^4x_1\cdots d^4x_n\:.$$
It is worth noticing that $\hat{\cal L}_I(x)$ includes only **free field operators** as we are dealing with the so-called interaction picture, so 
everything is explicitely known, commutation relations of field operators in particular.  Since the Lagrangian functions are scalars, we have:
$$U_\Lambda\hat{\cal L}_I(x) U^\dagger_\Lambda = \hat{\cal L}_I(\Lambda^{-1} x)\qquad (1)$$
Moreover, in view of free fields commutation relations one also has:$$[\hat{\cal L}_I(x), \hat{\cal L}_I(y)]=0 \qquad (2)$$ 
if $x$ and $y$ are spacelike separated.
The fact that $S$ is  invariant under the action of orthochronous Lorentz group is quite obvious 
$$U_\Lambda SU_\Lambda^\dagger = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{i^n}{n!} \int\cdots \int U_\Lambda T[ \hat{\cal L}_I(x_1)\cdots
\hat{\cal L}_I(x_n)]U_\Lambda^\dagger \:d^4x_1\cdots d^4x_n$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{i^n}{n!} \int\cdots \int T[U_\Lambda \hat{\cal L}_I(x_1)U_\Lambda^\dagger\cdots U_\Lambda
\hat{\cal L}_I(x_n)U_\Lambda^\dagger] \:d^4x_1\cdots d^4x_n$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{i^n}{n!} \int\cdots \int T[\hat{\cal L}_I(\Lambda^{-1} x_1)\cdots 
\hat{\cal L}_I(\Lambda^{-1}x_n)] \:d^4x_1\cdots d^4x_n$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{i^n}{n!} \int\cdots \int T[\hat{\cal L}_I(x_1)\cdots 
\hat{\cal L}_I(x_n)] \:d^4x_1\cdots d^4x_n$$
due to the Lorentz invariance of the measure $d^4x$.
The identity:
$$U_\Lambda T[ \hat{\cal L}_I(x_1)\cdots
\hat{\cal L}_I(x_n)]U_\Lambda^\dagger= T[U_\Lambda \hat{\cal L}_I(x_1)U_\Lambda^\dagger\cdots U_\Lambda
\hat{\cal L}_I(x_n)U_\Lambda^\dagger]$$
is consequence of the definition of $T$-ordinator, (1), and (2) for spacelike separated arguments, considering all cases concerning the time order of $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ and the fact that $\Lambda$ does not change the temporal order for causally related arguments as it belongs to the orthochronous  subgroup.

For more complicated theories the result is not obvious and it could be false in its elementary formulation based on canonical quantization, excluding the case of gauge theories, where it can be proved separately.

Regarding Weinberg's statement about **Lorentz covariance of the $S$ matrix** and **Lorentz invariance of $S$ operator**, if I understood well the definition, I think that it works like this.

Let us start from the full (interacting) theory. There are vectors $\Psi^\pm_{\{p_i\}}$ describing states which, at late time (respectively $t\to +\infty$ and $t\to -\infty$) evolve like free particle states with momenta $\{p_i\}$. The correspondingly associated free states, **always evolving in accordance witht he free theory**, are indicated by $\Phi_{\{p_i\}}$.
The $S$-matrix is the matrix of elements:
$$\langle \Psi^+_{\{q_i\}}|\Psi^-_{\{p_i\}}\rangle =  \langle \Phi_{\{q_i\}}|S\Phi_{\{p_i\}}\rangle\:.\qquad(3)$$
In the RHS the $S$ operator takes place. In view of it, the scattering process is completely described in terms of free states.

To say that the $S$ matrix is Lorentz covariant should mean (as far as I understand):
$$\langle \Psi^+_{\{\Lambda q_i\}}|\Psi^-_{\{\Lambda p_i\}}\rangle = \langle \Psi^+_{\{q_i\}}|\Psi^-_{\{p_i\}}\rangle\quad \forall \Lambda \in O(3,1)\uparrow\:, \forall \{\Lambda q_i\}\:, \{\Lambda p_i\}\:.$$
From (3), it immediately entails:
$$ \langle \Phi_{\{\Lambda q_i\}}|S\Phi_{\{\Lambda p_i\}}\rangle =  \langle \Phi_{\{q_i\}}|S\Phi_{\{p_i\}}\rangle\:.\qquad(4)$$
If $U_\Lambda$ is the unitary representation of $O(3,1)\uparrow$ on free states, so that $\Phi_{\{\Lambda p_i\}}= U_\Lambda \Phi_{\{p_i\}}$, we therefore have:
$$\langle U_\Lambda \Phi_{\{ q_i\}}|S U_\Lambda\Phi_{\{p_i\}}\rangle =  \langle \Phi_{\{q_i\}}|S\Phi_{\{p_i\}}\rangle\:,$$
that is 
$$\langle \Phi_{\{ q_i\}}|U^\dagger_\Lambda  S U_\Lambda\Phi_{\{p_i\}}\rangle =  \langle \Phi_{\{q_i\}}|S\Phi_{\{p_i\}}\rangle\:,$$ and so:
$$\langle \Phi_{\{ q_i\}}| \left( U^\dagger_\Lambda  S U_\Lambda - S\right) \Phi_{\{p_i\}}\rangle =  0\:,$$ 
Since the set of vectors $\Phi_{\{p_i\}}$ forms a basis of the Hilbert space (of the free theory) in view of the **asymptotic completeness** hypotheses, we conclude that:
$$U^\dagger_\Lambda  S U_\Lambda - S=0$$
i.e.
$$S=U_\Lambda  S U^\dagger_\Lambda\:, \quad \forall \Lambda \in O(3,1)\uparrow\:.$$
In other words if the $S$ matrix is **Lorentz covariant**, then  the $S$ operator is **Lorentz invariant**.

Comment: For me it is not obvious since the operation of chronological ordering of two points is poincare invariant only if there points are divided by the timelike or light-like interval (we talk about orthochronous subgroup).

Comment: In the remaining cases the lagrangians commute so that $T$ can be omitted...

Comment: yes, they must commute if S-operator must be lorentz invariant operator. But one part of my question was about how do we conclude that it is lorentz invariant from the fact of the poincare-covariance of s-matrix. Can you explain it, if you please?

Comment: No there is no logical loop, since in the interaction picture they commute just in view of the free field commutation relations, and the fact that ${\cal L}_I$ is a scalar.

Comment: Sorry I did not read well that part of your question. I do not understand what 'covariance' of S matrix should mean actually here...

Comment: These statements are represented in Weinberg's QFT. Maybe, I have distorted them little.
Weinberg first introduces s-matrix as
$$
S_{\beta \alpha} = \langle \Psi^{-}_{\beta}|\Psi^{+}_{\alpha} \rangle ,
$$
where $\Psi^{\pm }$ refer to the eigenfunctions of the full hamiltonian.

Comment: This expression is Poincare-covariant, i.e., we can expand left and right vectors in definition in Fock basis.
Then Weinberg says that for simplification of analisys of poincare-covariance of S-matrix we can represent it in a form
$$
S_{\beta \alpha} = \langle \Psi_{\beta}|\hat {S}| \Psi_{\alpha} \rangle ,
$$
where $\Psi_{\beta}, \Psi_{\beta}$ are the eigenstates of the free hamiltonian. This expression is Poincare covariant if and only if $\hat {S}$ is Poincare scalar.

Comment: But anyway, I have the next question according to your answer: why do we must assume that the lagrangians commute in case of spacelike intervals if we don't know that $s$-operator must be Lorentz invariant?

Comment: I do not uderstand well Weinberg's notion of covariance here. Regarding your last question, just free field theory is sufficient. Costruct a scalar field ${\cal L}_I$ using elementary free fields of any spin. Free fields commute or anticommute for spacelike separation. Hwever, since ${\cal L}_I$ is a scalar, fermions must be combined into currents to construct it and commutation relations finally arise for composite fields...

Comment: Usually we conclude that free fields commute for spacelike separated points when analysing causality principle or when we know that s-operator must be Lorentz invariant. For S-operator these ways are independent. So first I want to know why S-operator is lorentz invariant without causality principle. After that I can also conclude that fields must commute for spacelike intervals.

Comment: Well, in this case it is not necessary to use any property of $S$ operator since only free fields appear inside Dyson's expansion (as one deals with the interaction picture). Causal properties of free fields are completely encompassed by their causal propagators (advanced minus retarded fundamental solutions) which are known before scattering theory.

Comment: I changed my answer, please have a look at it.